# Both HTTP and SOCKS inbounds are not enabled - Qv2ray

Tags: 22.04, proxy

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and I want to use Qv2ray for proxy. After importing the server configuration, couldn't connect to it showing this error.
These are the logs in the terminal.

```
[V2RayInteraction] V2Ray version: V2Ray 4.28.2 (V2Fly, a community-driven edition of V2Ray.) Custom (go1.15.2 linux/amd64)
[V2RayInteraction] Starting V2Ray core with test options
[V2RayInteraction] Config file check passed.
[V2RayInteraction] V2Ray kernel process status changed: Starting
[V2RayInteraction] V2Ray kernel process status changed: Running
[V2RayInteraction] Starting API
[MainWindowExtra] Neither of HTTP nor SOCKS is enabled, cannot set system proxy. 

[gRPCBackend] gRPC Version: 1.19.1 
[gRPCBackend] API call returns: 14 (Connect Failed) 
[gRPCBackend] API call returns: 14 (channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE)
```

And this is the error pop-up in the GUI.

[image: Error popup image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's too late now, but it might help someone else.
I have no solid information about v2ray and qv2ray but I have working heavy on it recently. I think you must go to `preferences` then click on `inbound setting` tabs and checks `Socks settings` and `HTTP settings`
[Qv2ray Inbound Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0donw.png)

Comment: In my case, I only had to enable it. Thanks.